# aSmack Android documentation and debugging

Tags: android, xmpp, asmack

ASmack library refers to the documentation at http://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/smack/docs/latest/documentation/index.html
which I think it is outdated and does not provide accurate info. Examples are the following:
- Debugging:

```
        XMPPConnection.DEBUG_ENABLED = true;
```

-- even in the latest Readme file, it is not working:

```
XMPPConnection.DEBUG
```

this is not working.
- Also,  ChatManager: 1st (in docs) is not working, 2nd after googling...

```
 ChatManager chatmanager = connection.getChatManager();

 ChatManager chatmanager = ChatManager.getInstanceFor(connection);
```

So how I can enable verbose debugging as this what I get in the log cat using the basic sample in the documentation:

```
05-26 11:15:11.237    4633-4633/com.ex.myapplication4.app W/System.err﹕ org.jivesoftware.smack.SmackException$ConnectionException
05-26 11:15:11.237    4633-4633/com.ex.myapplication4.app W/System.err﹕ at org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPTCPConnection.connectUsingConfiguration(XMPPTCPConnection.java:455)
05-26 11:15:11.237    4633-4633/com.ex.myapplication4.app W/System.err﹕ at org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPTCPConnection.connect(XMPPTCPConnection.java:865)
```

And where I can find a reliable documentation or tutorial that works with the latest version (a)Smack 4.0.0-rc2 ?

Comment: I have the same problem like you. Today do you know where we can learn about asmack 4?

Comment: one possibility is to use asmack-android-7-beem-jingle.jar, It has been widely recovered and it works pretty well with my implementation.

Comment: Until asmack team publish asmack 4 docs, i am decide to continue using asmack-android-9-0.8.9 version. It's a shame but we can't doing nothing more...

Comment: Let's do something about it! Please, give us a documentation! A crowd documentation, this way we own could build based on our own experiences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used asmack-android-7-beem-jingle.jar for XMPP msgs over Android and it works pretty fine.
I created a gist for the code I used: https://gist.github.com/aselims/92da8b2ad3692fdec699
I hope this helps!

Comment: That jar is 3 years old. The used Smack version contains security vulnerabilities. I recommend **not using it**.

Comment: I agree but it could be used for testing purposes as the latest smack does not have a proper documentation.

Comment: I dispute that "the latest smack does not have a proper documentation". See https://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/smack/docs/latest/documentation/ if you find errors in the documentation, then you should report those in the Smack Users forum: https://community.igniterealtime.org/welcome I'm sure the developers would be happy about every report.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't answer your question.

But I was stucked on same (using aSmack 4.0 - **asmack-android-8-4.0.0.jar**):

```
06-17 13:42:22.466: W/System.err(16848): org.jivesoftware.smack.SmackException$ConnectionException
06-17 13:42:22.466: W/System.err(16848):    at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection.connectUsingConfiguration(XMPPTCPConnection.java:431)
06-17 13:42:22.467: W/System.err(16848):    at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection.connectInternal(XMPPTCPConnection.java:799)
06-17 13:42:22.467: W/System.err(16848):    at org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection.connect(XMPPConnection.java:391)
```

And I discovered what was the problem (*if you want details please ask*).

**Does your connection is running on main thread?** I solved that problem putting the code over `AsyncTask`, `doInBackground` method.

Comment: I do not use Smack 4.0, I use Smack asmack-android-7-beem-jingle.jar and to a great extent it is working out.

Comment: You can get detailed debug info through: ConnectionConfiguration connConfig = new ConnectionConfiguration(HOST, PORT);
connConfig.setDebuggerEnabled(true);